# Improve page performance by reducing number of binding with AngularJS?

Tags: performance, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

### Context

I'm building a list a results where each result can be edited by users.

### Approach

Currently I'm repeating the visible `<span>` tag that displays a result as well as the hidden `<input>` tag used to edit this same result. See the last `<td>` :

```html
<tr ng-repeat="entry in paginateDict | orderBy:predicate:reverse" class="form-inline" role="form">
  <!-- Edit buttons -->
  <td>
    <div class="radio">
      <label ng-hide="editMode" title="edit">
        <input class="sr-only" type="radio" name="edit"
         data-ng-click="editMode=true">
         <span tooltip="edit" class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></span>
       </label>

      <label ng-show="editMode" title="save">
        <input class="sr-only" type="radio" name="edit"
         ng-model="editMode" ng-click="submitEntry(true)">
        <span tooltip="save" class="fa fa-save fa-lg text-primary"></span>
      </label>

      <label ng-show="editMode" title="cancel">
        <input class="sr-only" type="radio" name="edit"
         ng-model="editMode" ng-click="submitEntry(false)">
        <span tooltip="undo" class="fa fa-times fa-lg text-danger"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <!-- Content -->
  <td ng-show="pyn" lang="cmn-py" data-id="{{entry.cid}}">
    <span ng-hide="editMode">{{entry.pyn | pinyin }}</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{entry.pyn}}" ng-model="entry.pyn" ng-show="editMode" class="form-control">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Each line as 5 editable columns and each column as two binding (on `<span>` and `<input>`).

## Question

In order to improve page performance, by reducing the number of binding, is there an `Angular` way to dynamically create and attach the `<input>` to a row when the *edit* radio button is click ?

Comment: may be a directive but you should test performance because of there is no binding but dom manipulation so I think it's better teh angular way but I don't really know ^^

Comment: This is essentially the flyweight pattern in Angular. I haven't seen anything like it, and never got down to actually write it myself, although it would be very useful. It would be doable as Whisher says - just make sure you have a performance problem indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [ngIf directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead of ng-show

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}.

```
<td ng-show="pyn" lang="cmn-py" data-id="{{entry.cid}}">
   <span ng-hide="editMode">{{entry.pyn | pinyin }}</span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="{{entry.pyn}}" ng-model="entry.pyn" ng-if="editMode" class="form-control">
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, it's removed completely from the DOM until `editMode` is true again.